# Create convex hull around points with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, kineticjs, convex-hull

I want to create a hull around images created with KineticJS.

1 - I save all vertices of the images in an array with [x,y]:

```
var points = [[0, 0], [0,350], [170, 0], [170, 300], [135, 135] , [135, 435], [305, 135], [305, 435]];
```

2 - I want to create a convex hull around the points

3 - after, I want to set the distance of the hull a little bit higher, so all objects can be in the hull.

I found a [javascript implementation](http://en.literateprograms.org/Quickhull_%28Javascript%29) for creating a convex hull online and tried to bind this in my KineticJS Script.

But I get an error:
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded 
in the buildConvexHull function:

```
allBaseLines.push(baseLine)
```

My code is in a fiddle but it doesn't work...
http://jsfiddle.net/gvFrd/5/

Comment: It may be that the convex hull algorithm expects a list of pairs in `points`. You have first the list of x and then the list of y coordinates.

Comment: I changed the structure to var points = [[0, 0], [0,350], [170, 0], [170, 300], [135, 135] , [135, 435], [305, 135], [305, 435]];

But the error doesn't disappear.

Comment: The for loop seems strange. Try to combine both lines, `for( var pt in points)`. But then maybe I do not know enough about JS.

Comment: Thanks, that was not the fault, but so I recognized that I'm too stupid for copy and paste...The function was the same as getConvexHull...

I updated all, but the error is that the baseline is not defined...

Answer (score 5):

Hull.js looks like the answer you are looking for.  After making a convex hull it can also push the edges inward and generate more segments to get what looks like a pretty accurate outline.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/hull.js

Comment: that hull is for node.js, any others for client side?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

A simple algorithm is to divide the set of points into 2 half sets and find the 3 farthest points and triangulate the points. Each point inside the triangle is then in the convex hull. Then repeat the steps for the other points. Search for the  quick hull algorithm. You can also use a delaunay triangulation.  You can download my convex hull class @ phpclasses.org. It uses a delaunay triangulation.

Comment: Seems like Andrew's Algorithm would be simpler to implement.